# How to ensure smooth transaction between 2 users of my website

Tags: security, e-commerce

First of all, i'm not sure if this is the right place for this kind of question, so if anyone wants to point me in a better direction, do not hesitate!

I'm currently working on a website that will allow users to trade real physical objects between eachother. For exemple, User 1 trades a rare collectible coin, to User 2, which in turns sends an other collectible coin that he has double of.

What would be the safest way for me to make sure that both parties get their coins, without anyone getting scammed ?

I already figured that I'd be using the Paypal API to check for a "Verified address".
For now, it isn't viable for me to receive both package and "re-ship" them.
I was thinking of maybe holding an amount on both credit card until both confirm delivery, but i guess that one can receive a package and say he never received it.

Edit : Would it be too much of a trouble for the user if i force them to use a shipping method and print a "shipping sticker" that i create when they both agree to do the transaction? That way it would force them to use a signature shipping method.

All ideas are more than welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There really is not a 100% way to avoid a scam as a buyer can always come back and say they did not receive the item, it was damaged, not as described, file a dispute/chargeback or etc.  However PayPal does have buyer and seller protections that come into play as well that help to protect buyers from such things.  Plus PayPal's fraud filters and screenings some of the best in the industry.

Comment: My problem is that they will not do a payment with Paypal. My website would basically put together 2 people looking to trade things. No money involved

Comment: Your best option will probably be then to require a signature on delivery shipping method like you mentioned.  Then using API's to connect to the shipping providers and check status, updates and etc.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into that! I'm going to wait a little before accepting the answer :)